# Failing Output in Python

Tags: python

The goal is to create a class object for a grocery list then output the list. Output should say something like "Item 1...Enter the item name:" but with the input's item show as well. Here is my current code:

```py
class ItemToPurchase:

    def __init__(self):
        self.item_name = "none"
        self.item_price = 0.0
        self.item_quantity = 0
        
    def print_item_cost(self, item_name, item_price, item_quantity):
        return (item_quantity * item_price)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    items=[]
    for i in range(2):
          item_name=input("Enter the item name:\n")
          item_price=float(input("Enter the item price:\n"))
          item_quantity = int(input("Enter the item quantity:\n"))
          items.append(item_name)
          items.append(item_price)
          items.append(item_quantity)
    
    one = items[0:3:1]
    two = items[3:6:1]
    objs1 = ItemToPurchase()
    res1 = objs1.print_item_cost(one[0], one[1], one[2])
    objs2 = ItemToPurchase()
    res2 = objs2.print_item_cost(two[0], two[1], two[2])
    result = res1+res2

    print("TOTAL COST:\n",result)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and *ask a question*. *What happens when you run the code*? How is that *different* from what is supposed to happen? *What do you think is causing* the problem, based on your [investigation](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? *Why* do you need help to fix this - what specifically don't you understand about it? After explaining these things, write your own question, starting with a question word like "how" or "why", and ending with a `?`.

Comment: Please also read the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you understand how to post code formatted exactly as you have it.

Comment: `item_name=input(f"Item {i}... Enter the item name:\n")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Kyle your code is proper but you didn't communicate your problem very well.
I am assuming that you want output with text.

For that you have to updatee your `print_item_cost()` function as:

```
    def print_item_cost(self, item_name, item_price, item_quantity):
        print(f'Item Name: {item_name}')
        print(f'Item Price: {item_price}')
        print(f'Item Quantity: {item_quantity}')
        return (item_quantity * item_price)
```

Then your output format will be:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJYYT.png)